# Java IDE that is compatible with git

Tags: java, ide, git

I have done many Java projects in the past and recently I have been working on python projects out of a git repo. I liked git so much I would like to start applying it my Java projects, but I would still like to work out of a Java IDE. I would like to know if there is a Java IDE that does the following:

- Can clone a project given the ssh/http address.
- Can run git commands (checkout, status, push, pull, ect).
- Can show a network graph of the project commits.
- Can add and unadd files to be committed.
- Can easily checkout, commit, and push new branches.

Even if it has only some of these features, it would be great to hear about it.

Comment: Do you really feel this question is constructive?

Comment: Is it not? An IDE is an important software tool for a lot of developers and git is a useful version control tool. Why not see an IDE that can use git without command line calls to git?

Comment: All three mainstream IDEs for Java are compatible with Git (you can see them listed below). Which one would you choose?

Comment: @leventov But git support in all three IDEs has many differences/issues

Comment: @leventov the one that works best. And just from these posts 2 of the 3 have major bugs associated with them.

Comment: @MariuszS I can't draw out that differences from the answers, can you?

Comment: @Dom That's like asking whether Red, Blue, or Yellow is "the best". All the answers have the same major qualities that you're asking for. Is there a specific feature that you're looking for that you've not found in your current IDE?

Comment: @leventov Yes, from my comments :) IntelliJ has broken many git flows for long time (amending, gerrit and push). Answers are wrong

Comment: @leventov see this meta post regarding "best" http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/157/is-it-acceptable-to-use-best-in-a-question

Comment: @MariuszS in my experience, IntelliJ has far more pleasant Git support, than Eclipse.

Comment: "pleasant" - what this mean? pleasant and best are not good for this site :D

Answer (score 9):

[Netbeans](https://netbeans.org/) has a Git support out-of-the-box.

Nevertheless in our company we are discouraged to use it, as it has/had a bug which led to some trouble with the git repo.
Unfortunately I don't know what the bug was, as it occurred before I worked there.
Therefor we use git only from the command line, which is quite easy too.
This leads also to no trouble because Netbeans notices external changes in the files and also in the git repo itself.

e.g. if you perform `git checkout my_branch` Netbeans notices the changes in the files and also shows you the right branch in which you are currently working.

Comment: +1 netbeans. Also worth mentioning it supports local Git and SVN as well. And as for the bug, how long did it occur before? If long time already then I think Netbeans has release many versions after that, therefore, I don't think that will be a problem anymore. .

Comment: Actually I also think that the bug is no problem anymore. But I thought it is worth mentioning.

Comment: Off-topic: On the other side git is really easy to use from the command line and I think it is "bad" if you rely on your IDE to be able to use it. For myself it often occurs that I need to clone some repo only to try a program or it is also useful if you want to manage your Latex documents etc... But that's only my off-topic opinion. ;)

Comment: yup, true :D I'm even using tortoiseSVN now :D :D

Comment: +1 Netbeans is really cool here especially because it listens to external changes in the files and thus is much better at inter operating with other tools (like a CLI VCS)

Answer (score 6):

[Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/) supports most or all of those functions via the [EGit plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/egit/). I know other developers who like it, though I personally prefer to just use the git CLI.

Comment: Very powerful git support and gerrit

Comment: Would definitely recommend Eclipse for new users.

Answer (score 5):

**[IntelliJ Idea](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/)** has [Git integration](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/using-git-integration.html). It's quite powerful, and should be just fine for most peoples' needs.

It should be good for...

- Changing branches
- Pulls, Pushes, Checkouts, etc...
- Adding and rm'ing files
- Etc...

Comment: Many issues here, push [IDEA-98693](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-98693) gerrit support [IDEA-60528](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-60528) and amending [IDEA-79098](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-79098) is broken

Comment: For my own git workflow the only problem I have is the inability of Intellij to push tags back to remote repo

Comment: All those issues are fixed or dupplicates of fixed now.